# Create a post on the wall from the app with additional parameters ("to" and "status_type")

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall

Exploring wall posts with graph explorer I've mentioned that there are some posts, which have **"to"** field and their **status_type** is **app_created_story**. As I understand this is a way to post on friends wall. How this type of posts are done? I've tried to set these fields and used both application and user tokens but haven't succeeded.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer to this question is that an application can no longer post on a friends wall. The official blog post [can be seen here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/). You'll need to scroll down a little bit to the sections labeled
"Deprecating features that lead to low quality user experiences".

> Post to friends wall via the API generate a high levels of negative
>   user feedback, including “Hides” and “Mark as Spam" and so we are
>   removing it from the API. If you want to allow people to post to their
>   friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the feed dialog.
>   Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action
>   tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend
>   approves the tag).

Comment: I know that app can't post to friends wall. But what I've seen is that some app did it (post made few days ago, after February 6th breaking changes). And this particular post had status_type set to app_created_story.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the publishing section of the GraphAPI.  See if that can perhaps solve your issue.

[GraphAPI - Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/)

After a quick glance over that documentation, it seems like you could come right by using the /feed connection where you may have previously used /posts.  I am sure there is more to it though, but just thought I'd share this and see if it can point you in a useful direction.